# Is Windows Azure AppFabric Service Discontinued?

Tags: azure, appfabric

I am using Azure, and Microsoft offers a service to work with AppFabric in the cloud, there are many articles around the Web about this service in the cloud, but I do not find it in Azure, you'd tell me if this service was renamed and that's why I can not find or was it discontinued?

Answer (score 5):

The services were renamed. Initially, Microsoft used the tag *AppFabric* for two different things:

- Windows **Server** AppFabric (local computer)
- Windows **Azure** AppFabric (cloud services)

[In 2012, Microsoft dropped the *AppFabric* tag from their **Azure** offerings:](http://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-renames-azure-services)

- AppFabric Cache -->  Cache ([to be retired and replaced by Redis Cache on November 30, 2016](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-faq/#which-azure-cache-offering-is-right-for-me))
- AppFabric Service Bus --> Service Bus
- AppFabric Access Control --> Access Control

Comment: I'm using ServiceBus! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

According to the [official AppFabric blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabric/archive/2015/06/19/appfabric-1-1-for-windows-server-support-lifecycle-extension-4-11-2017.aspx), the support is extended to 2017.

They also [recommended](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabric/archive/2015/04/02/windows-server-appfabric-1-1-ends-support-4-2-2016.aspx) how to migrate the AppFabric services to the new Azure offerings, for example, using Azure Redis Cache for Caching scenarios.

Comment: Thank you, this has help me, I'll use Redis

Comment: I'm glad :) Please [mark the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so others can benefit from it.