# Disabling Azure AppFabric Cache Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, caching, appfabric-cache, azure-appfabric

I am working on an upgrade for a website which was developed back in 2013. In the website, Azure AppFabric is used for caching. I hosted the site on my local IIS.  When I navigate to the site, I get the following error:

```
[SocketException (0x2af9): No such host is known]
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AsyncResultNoResult.EndInvoke() +84
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.TcpClientChannelFactory.TcpConnectionCallback(IAsyncResult result) +126

[DataCacheException: ErrorCode<ERRCA0017>:SubStatus<ES0006>:There is a temporary failure. Please retry later. (One or more specified cache servers are unavailable, which could be caused by busy network or servers. For on-premises cache clusters, also verify the following conditions. Ensure that security permission has been granted for this client account, and check that the AppFabric Caching Service is allowed through the firewall on all cache hosts. Also the MaxBufferSize on the server must be greater than or equal to the serialized object size sent from the client.). Additional Information : The client was trying to communicate with the server: net.tcp://mydomain.cache.windows.net:24233.]
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.ThrowException(ErrStatus errStatus, Guid trackingId, Exception responseException, Byte[][] payload, EndpointID destination) +392
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.EstablishConnection(IEnumerable`1 servers, RequestBody request, Func`3 sendMessageDelegate, DataCacheReadyRetryPolicy retryPolicy) +883
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SocketClientProtocol.SendReceive(IVelocityRequestPacket request, Func`2 delegate, EndpointID& destination) +49
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SocketClientProtocol.Initialize(IEnumerable`1 servers) +506
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.GetCache(String cacheName, CreateNewCacheDelegate cacheCreationDelegate, DataCacheInitializationViaCopyDelegate initializeDelegate) +499
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.CacheHelpers.RunCacheCreationHooks(CacheConnectingEventArgs fetchingEventArgs, IDataCacheFactory dataCacheFactory, Object sender, EventHandler`1 fetchingHandler, EventHandler`1 fetchedHandler) +101
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider.CreateInternalProvider(IHttpRuntime httpRuntime, SessionInitializationData initData, IDataCacheFactory dataCacheFactory, EventHandler`1 cacheFetching, EventHandler`1 cacheFetched) +136
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider.GetInternalProvider() +223
   Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider.CreateNewStoreData(HttpContext context, Int32 timeout) +19
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.InitStateStoreItem(Boolean addToContext) +122
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.CompleteAcquireState() +298
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +1226
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +625
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +195
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +128
```

The following namespaces are added in the project:

```
Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core
Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client
Microsoft.WindowsFabric.Common
Microsoft.WindowsFabric.Data.Common
```

**important details of Web.config:**

```
<section name="dataCacheClients" type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientsSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />

<dataCacheClients>
        <dataCacheClient name="default">
            <!--To use the in-role flavor of Windows Azure Cache, set identifier to be the cache cluster role name -->
            <!--To use the Windows Azure Cache Service, set identifier to be the endpoint of the cache cluster -->
            <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="mydomain.cache.windows.net" />
            <!--<localCache isEnabled="true" sync="TimeoutBased" objectCount="100000" ttlValue="300" />-->
            <!--Use this section to specify security settings for connecting to your cache. This section is not required if your cache is hosted on a role that is a part of your cloud service. -->
            <securityProperties mode="Message" sslEnabled="false">
                <messageSecurity authorizationInfo="info" />
            </securityProperties>
        </dataCacheClient>
    </dataCacheClients>

<caching>
    <outputCache enableOutputCache="false" />
        <outputCacheSettings>
            <outputCacheProfiles>
                <add name="CacheName" duration="20" varyByParam="*"/>
            </outputCacheProfiles>
         </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

Can someone please guide me on how I disable the cache or is there a way to emulate the AppFabric cache locally. Kindly pardon if my question is not clear (as this is my first experience with Azure AppFabric services.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This Stackoverflow thread gives some useful history on AppFabric, which was available on both Windows Server and Azure. Basically it's discontinued, and Microsoft recommend migrating to Azure Redis Cache. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34809759/is-windows-azure-appfabric-service-discontinued

Comment: Thanks. I'll surely try to migrate to redis cache. but to keep the site work on localhost, it is required to disable the cache.